# Combination of Values: Automated generation

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

How can I get a list of combinations for two values (e.g. 0 and a) such as for N=3:

```
{{a,a,a},{a,a,0},{a,0,a},{0,a,a},{a,0,0},{0,a,0},{0,0,a},{0,0,0}}
```

?

I'd like to do that for any arbitrary N.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this function [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html)

```
Tuples[{a, 0}, 3]
```